# how can I insert data in oracle AFTER a particular row that exist in the data table?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 10 rows of data in my table. now i want to insert a row of data just after the 9th data and before row 10..if am not mistaken ,in mysql db this thing is possible before there's a before and after clause, how bout in oracle ?

here's my starting insert statement, let's say i want to insert it after the 9th data ,how?

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (TITLE,DESCRIPTION,STATUS) VALUES ('blahblah','descriptionblah',1);
```

Comment: What is after and before? there is no order, it just saved. (of course under the hood there is an order, but why do you care about it?)

Comment: there is no such thing as "row 9" in a relational database

Comment: i was asked to add another row in a table. currently there are 10 rows of data in the table, and the new data i was asked to add, seems appropriate to be inserted before the last row..how to do that? do i need to re-input all the data so that they are arranged?

Comment: In Oracle there are no use to insert a new record between two existing records. The reason for these is that Oracle doesn't promise that the records will be stored and always kept in the same order as they are inserted. Oracle may at some time in the future for some reason decide to rearrange  the records!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no inherrent order to rows in a table, and there is no guarantee a particular ordering will be preserved between selects. **Consider adding a column containing the required ordering and when querying the table, order the result set by that column.**

To insert a row which should appear at a particular position in the result set, ensure that the value you place in the ordering column is appropriate.